# URL rewrite in opencart

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, opencart

How to rewrite the URL for my search page in opencart.
Current URL is:

```
http://IP/opencart/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=24
```

But I need to display it like:

```
http://localhost/opencart/product/search/42
```

or in any URL format that is an user friendly.
I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /opencart
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteBase /opencart 
RewriteRule ^search$ index.php?route=product/search  [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search$
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Rewriting OpenCart Products SEO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278642/url-rewriting-opencart-products-seo)

Answer (score 1):

How About this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /opencart
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^product/search/([0-9]*)$ index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=$1 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search$
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Tested works fine for me in `RewriteBase` provide your folder name

Answer (score 0):

You need to install extension which modify urls.